# How do I include and access a file within my installer custom action?

Tags: c#, installation

Very new to installers here. I want to include/bundle a certificate file with my installer. Then in my custom action, install that certificate. But I don't know a couple things

1. How do I include/bundle/embed my file
2. Once included, where do I read it from? Or how do I unbundle it during installation?

Comment: what tool are you using to build the installer? I hope you're not reinventing the wheel and using C# code to generate the MSI from scratch.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I'm using the built-in Visual Studio Installer project, with a custom install action to the output of a C# console project. This is my first time programming a installer, so I'm learning lots already. I can debug into my console project when installing just fine. I just don't know how to include and access my files in the setup.exe